# Bell number modulo prime power

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, bell-numbers

I'd like to ask how to fastly calculate the [Bell number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number) $B_n$ modulo a prime power, where $n$ is around one million.

Comment: This is the relevant problem http://www.javaist.com/rosecode/problem-511-Bell-Numbers-Modulo-Factorial-askyear-2018

Comment: The link just claims the problem. Nothing new.

Comment: I know. I just posted the link to give credit to the original source.

Comment: My source is from another forum earlier than that, anyway. Until now, there isn't an easy solution.

Comment: I found your question when trying to search for the paper ;)

Comment: see also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2919174

Comment: This might be of interest too: https://www.emis.de/journals/BBMS/Bulletin/bul964/Robert-Gertsch.pdf

Comment: @HangWu , can you please explain your solution?

Answer (score 2):

I'll answer my question by myself. [This paper](https://www.mathstat.dal.ca/FQ/Scanned/19-2/gessel.pdf) ("Congruences for Bell and Tangent Numbers" by Ira Gessel) proposed a favorable solution.

Comment: This paper does not answer the posed question. It may help to compute Bell numbers modulo a factorial of a small number, but not modulo a (large) prime power.

Comment: This is just a link, that can be made unavailable any time, please include important parts in the answer itself.

Comment: I've updated the title and author information.